# Vaadin 24 override styles for NavBar

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin24

The Vaadin 24 version has the following styles for `navbar`:

```
[part="navbar"] {
  min-height: var(--lumo-size-xl);
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--lumo-contrast-10pct);
}
```

I want to remove the following line:

```
min-height: var(--lumo-size-xl);
```

For this purpose I created the `vaadin-app-layout.css` file and placed to `mytheme\components` folder:

```
[part~="navbar"] {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--lumo-contrast-10pct);
}
```

But it has no effect. What am I doing wrong and how to correctly override this style?

**UPDATED**

I added `mytheme\components\vaadin-app-layout.css`

```
[part="navbar"] {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--lumo-contrast-10pct);
  min-height: unset;
}
```

but it doesn't work

Then I added to `styles.css`:

```
vaadin-app-layout::part(navbar) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid var(--lumo-contrast-10pct);
  min-height: unset;
}
```

and it works. Why it doesn't work for `vaadin-app-layout.css`?

Comment: Like with any css, if you don't override it the previous value is still in effect. So you have to add e.g. min-height: unset

Comment: Thank you! Please see my updated question.. it still doesn't work for vaadin-app-layout.css but works for styles.css. What am I doing wrong with vaadin-app-layout.css?

Comment: Not sure, but your solution based on styles.css is better in the long run - so you are good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, since Vaadin 24, you have to put CSS for customising Vaadin components into the directory `component-styles` inside of your theme directory (no longer just `components`).